# Null-terminate a string in MASM / GetModuleFileName

Tags: assembly, masm, null-terminated, getmodulefilename

In my program I call the `GetModuleFileName` function from the Windows API. The function tells me the path of the running .EXE file.

On Windows XP machines the string (*szSrc*) is not null-terminated according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
invoke GetModuleFileName,NULL,szSrc,255
```

How can I null-terminate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a zero to your variable at the end.

```
.data
szSrc db "Your string", 0
```

If you need to do it at runtime, you need to get the length of your variable (*szSrc*), and then you could write something like this:

```
lea eax, szSrc
mov byte ptr [eax+szSrcLen], 0
```

Note : it is important to provide a valid length. If you don't know the correct string length then it will be impossible to make a null string.

Comment: Just for the record, `mov byte ptr [eax+szSrcLen], 0` assumes that `szSrcLen` is a placeholder that you replace with whatever register you actually have it in.  Or that it's an EQU constant. (Or a bug in the asnwer). But *not* a memory location; it it's `sqSrcLen dd ?`, then you'd actually be indexing relative to where the length is stored, not using a length loaded from memory. x86 addressing modes don't have memory-indirect; if you want to use runtime-variable values as part of an addressing mode, they have to be in registers.  e.g. `mov byte ptr [szSrc + ecx], 0` where `ecx` holds a length.