# Writing Hello World in MASM

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I'd like to write super simple *Hello World* `Win32` program in `assembly` using the `printf` to compile with `ml` and `link` provided with my `MSVC`.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

EXTERN printf :PROC ; declare printf

.data
    HelloWorld db "Hello World!\n"

.code
main:
  push offset HelloWorld
  call printf
  ret
end main
```

I'm compiling it like that:

```
ml.exe /c HelloWorld.asm
```

And then linking:

```
link HelloWorld.obj libcmt.lib
```

without any problems BUT when i run it (under the `PowerShell`) the program doesn't display ANYTHING!

What's wrong whit the code and how to correct it to work?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33725587/2189500)?

Comment: Also you are missing the null terminator in your string.

Comment: Resolved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643447/how-to-compile-a-hello-world-assembly-on-windows/69654244#69654244

Comment: @CherryDT Sorry for a such an obvious question, but can You please tell me how does the string should be terminated in that case to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038040/1871033 - `HelloWorld db "Hello World!\n",0` - Without the null byte, `printf` wouldn't know where the string ends and would continue reading ad infinitum, into unrelated and possibly non-existing memory areas, which is undefined behavior. I think MASM should also support [`.asciiz`](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-20/ass20_2.html), in which case `HelloWorld: .asciiz "Hello World!\n"` would work too and do the same.